# PHP/Laravel - Query to get a row id from another table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have table 1 (T1) with a id row. I have a table 2 (T2) that i want to order by (updated_at, desc) and then get the 12 ids of the T1.(T2 have a row for T1 ids).

```
public function latest($limit = 12)
{       
    return $this->model->->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
}
```

This way i get the 12 ordered ids of the T1, but idk how to order by T2 table.

Comment: do you have any relation between them? And what is the foreign key

Comment: I am adjusting a script, i cant find where the relationships are made nor the foreign key. I am not very familiar with php/Laravel but i am trying hard to understand it to get where i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function latest($limit = 12)
{       
    return $this->model->->orderBy('T2.updated_at', 'T2.desc')
        ->limit($limit)
        ->join('T2','T1.id','=',$limit)
        ->get();
}
```

Try join query If you have reference for id for both table.Your code should some thing like above

Comment: It is a good method, but both tables have a updated_at row. So this will create a conflict , right?

Comment: Yeh ,but you can select them like this.

Comment: I have updated the answer,hope you can find the `T2.Updated_at`

Comment: This was it just dont show anything on the script home page. It is not suposed to use Facades to call the DB?